# Defining a category in the same .h/.m files of another class

Tags: objective-c

Is it a good practice to define a category within the same .h/.m files of another class? I know it will build with no error and be exactly the same as if it was defined separately.

The main reason I want to do this is because I'm working on an open source control and I want it to have a single .h/.m file.

Comment: Bad idea what you are thinking. Create separate file for each category

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, the biggest problem with combining multiple classes and categories into the same header/implementation is impaired searchability. When a class is in a file with another class, the file name will no longer reflect the fact that the header/implementation contains your other class, making it much harder for others to look for your class.

If your project is small and self-contained, however, the searchability is less of an issue. When there is only one file to search, there is no question of where each particular piece of code is: it's all in that one file. It sounds like your project is both small and self-contained, so I see no problem in placing all code in a single source file if you want it that way.

Another alternative could be placing each class and category in a separate header/implementation pair of files, and then defining a header that includes them all. This would let you keep an ideal project organization, and let your users include a single header to use your component.

Comment: +1 I'll add that this also makes more sense when there's semantic locality. E.g. if the category is small and directly related to the primary class, and that's obvious to consumers of the class, then it's more justifiable than if you're just throwing unrelated definitions together to avoid extra files.

Comment: My project is indeed small and self-contained. What you both said makes sense, so I'm going to go ahead and include the category in the same file. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If you need this category in just one place I’d say that it’s not that bad having the category within the `.m` file.

Obviously, if you need that category in multiple places, you should definitely move to its own file: the convention is to name it in this way:

```
BaseClass+categoryName.{h,m}
```

e.g.:

```
NSString+reverseString.h
NSString+reverseString.m
```

Comment: Me, too: If the extension is only used locally, I (sometimes) put it in the .m of the class, which needs it.